# ASP.NET MVC Template Helpers - How to Get Lower case ID's

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

When using the template helpers in ASP.NET MVC, e.g. `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Property)` the rendered Html with have a capitalized ID - matching my property name.

In order to standardize the ID's of all html elements I want this to be lower case. Rather than specifying the ID manually - which won't get updated if I rename my property, I'd like to establish a convention.

I'm sure I read this was possible somewhere and I'm currently scanning the interwebz to find it. But if anyone can help me and save me time, that would be awesome.

Comment: Thats a lot of work for little gain.  If your worried about standardizing the access with javascript or jquery selectors consider that if you change a property name you'll still have to adjust the jquery anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently ASP.NET MVC doesn't offer any extension points allowing you to do this.

Comment: Do you have confirmation for this?

Comment: I can't reference anything on the web - as far as I remember, I checked this using .NET Reflector before answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `Html.EditorFor`;  this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) can get you started.

Or you use this:

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.Property).ToString().ToLower()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am hoping ideally to not even need to do this though. I am pretty sure I've seen a way to do it. Good comment for anyone else who stumbles upon this question though.

Comment: This won't work: `EditorFor` returns `IHtmlString`, but converting it to string will result in its future html encoding (at least, in MVC 3). Workaround is `(new HtmlString(Html.EditorFor(x => x.Property).ToString().ToLower())`.

Comment: Also note that you'll change the case of all the other letters there. E.g. of `name`. So likely, you won't be able to update the model after doing this.

Comment: I don't think model binding is case sensitive. If it is I'll create my own model binder.

Comment: I ended up writing my own templates for each of my requirements, but fortunately, model binding is not case-sensitive. Very unfortunate that no other way around it.